# Error: EACCES: permission denied using webpack

Tags: npm, terminal, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm attempting to use webpack for the first time and I'm getting this error,

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/dist'
    at Error (native)
```

when trying to run my production script.

A `sudo chown -R 'whoami' /dist` came back with `chown: /dist: No such file or directory`.

How can I go about resolving this?

Comment: Is `/dist` (in the root of your filesystem) really the correct location for your production code?

Comment: try removing the slash

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As Camp bell mentioned you need to remove forward slash before dist folder in the output path section.

In my case I had to remove forward slash before build. Check my example below

**Wrong one:**

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "/build/"), //remove forward slash here
    publicPath: "/",
    filename: "bundle.js"
}
```

**Correct one:**

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build/"),
    publicPath: "/",
    filename: "bundle.js"
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, in this case, it's likely that **permission denied** is just a result, not a real cause of error.

Most likely, you carelessly wrote `./` as `/` in the configuration code. Because, npm really can't access path `/`; this path is outside the user directory `~`. `npm`, usually installed in the user directory. Just like:

```
$ type npm
npm is /Users/somebody/.nvm/versions/node/v12.2.0/bin/npm
```

So, Check the configuration file carefully. Hope to help you.